# Limit of the function vs. limit of its average

Tags: limits, definite-integrals, average

Is it true that if $(b-a)$ is fixed, then $\lim \limits_{a,b \to \infty}\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(t)dt=\lim \limits_{t \to \infty}f(t)$? The function $f(t)$ isn't too nice, it's stochastic, involves jumps etc., so mean value theorem wouldn't work.
Intuitively, it should be true. If it isn't in general, are there any conditions under which it would be true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $b-a$ is fixed, then it's fixed to some constant $c$

The limit then becomes

$$\lim_{a\to\infty}\frac{1}{c}\int_a^{a+c} f(t)dt$$

Now, if $\lim_{t\to\infty} f(t)$ **exists** and is equal to $L$, then we know that for each $\epsilon>0$, there exists some $M>0$ such that if $x>M$, then $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$.

Therefore, if $a>M$, you know that $$\int_a^{a+c} f(t)dt < \int_a^{a+c} (L+\epsilon)dt = c(L+\epsilon)$$

and $$\int_a^{a+c} f(t)dt > \int_a^{a+c} (L-\epsilon)dt = c(L-\epsilon)$$

which should be enough to prove your statement.

---

However, if the limit of $f$ does **not** exist, then the limit of the integral can still exist, but then the equality does not hold anymore (since one side of the equality is undefined)

Comment: Sounds too easy to be true, but it seems that you're right, thank you! I upvoted, but I don't have enough reputation for it to be recorded...

Comment: $@5xum$ There's a mistake in a way you calculate the intergrals. They should be $(L-\varepsilon)c$ and $(L+\varepsilon)c$. Which means that the limit we're interested in equals $cL$ , not $L$.

Comment: @Paula Well, there's also the $\frac1c$ in front of the integral, so the limit is still $L$. But yes, I was a little sloppy.

Comment: sorry, I didn't notice. Now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Define $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ by

$f(x)=1$ , if $x \notin \mathbb Z$  and $f(x)=0$ if $x \in \mathbb Z$ .

If $b>a$, then $\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(t)dt=1$, but the limit $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)$ does not exist.

Comment: It's a good counterexample.